# Properties Reader does not read properties

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

In my project I'm trying to read some data from properties file. I wrote the PropertiesReader class which looks like this:

```java
public class PropertiesReader {
    private final Properties properties;

    public PropertiesReader(String propertyFileName) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream(propertyFileName);
        this.properties = new Properties();
        this.properties.load(is);
    }

    public String getProperty(String propertyName) {
        return this.properties.getProperty(propertyName);
    }
}
```

It works just fine in one of modules in the project, but in the second one I get an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: inStream parameter is null

The code of the second module looks like this:

```java
public class OutputAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PropertiesReader properties = new PropertiesReader("properties.properties");

        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://" + properties.getProperty("activemq-host"));
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();   
        ...  
    }
}
```

This is the file structure I have:

[image: This is the file structure I have]

And that's how I declared resources in pom:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
</build>
```

Comment: When it fail dit does so when called from the main method. Most likely the class loader can't find the properties in the same way as in the other module.

Comment: I load properties the same way in the other module, it's just PropertiesReader propertiesReader = new PropertiesReader("properties.properties");

Comment: `if (is == null) { throw new IOException("unable to load file \"" + propertyFileName + "\" (" + getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(".") + ")"); }`

Comment: @user16320675 ok, it says that the reader tries to get properties from 
/home/hellmick/kalinowm/Packages/src/output/toRest/target/classes/
but it suppose to get it from /home/hellmick/kalinowm/Packages/src/output/toRest/src/main/resources. What should I do to change it? I've declared the resources path in pom.

Comment: @user16320675 it tries to load the properties.properties file, as it should, but not from the target directory.

Comment: delete `.idea` folder from the root of your project and import the `pom.xml` in to IntelliJ as project and try.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam I did it, same result.

Comment: @user16320675 I guess it was, it works as a Maven project in Intellij, the pom file seems fine to me I guess, https://pastebin.com/dgPR2XNL here's the full one.

Comment: maybe starting the JAR works (assuming one is built)

Comment: Could you please post the screenshot of project settings and in modules check the sources tab it should be like in the following link https://i.imgur.com/fM3pjJC.png

Comment: `PropertiesReader properties = new PropertiesReader("/properties.properties");` Your properties file is in the right place

Comment: btw afaik `Properiies.load` doesn't auto-close the stream so use try-with-resources

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam https://imgur.com/a/H3LFt42

Comment: @g00se that was not it, now I get unable to load file "/properties.properties" (file:/home/hellmick/kalinowm/Packages/src/output/toRest/target/classes/)

Comment: @Hellmick everything looks fine. I'm not sure what the issue is. I not able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @user16320675 I've built the jar file and it works. Thank you!

Comment: *@g00se that was not it,,,* in that case, it looks like IntelliJ has broken Maven - needless to say NOT a good sign. Or, you might have broken your pom.xml